# Log in with Facebook in passport.js without setting password

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, authentication, passport.js

I am using `passport.js` to enable users to log in with Facebook.

However, using the documentation and different tutorials, it seems it's common to let the user log in with Facebook and automatically create a local account, but without setting the password.

Wouldn't it be best practice to require the user to set a password after logging in with Facebook? It seems wrong that you can have a user without having a password.

Comment: Why do they need to have a password if they already logged in?

Comment: In this example, facebook is being used to auth your user and log them into your site. So the password is their facebook password, you just dont get access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your user has a password when using Facebook Strategy, you just dont have to worry about what it is.**

[Passport-local Strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) is provided specifically for creating in-house username/pass combos. They are unnecessary, unless your app requires them. Giving people the option of setting an email/pass login after creating an account is sometimes done, but not required to be "more secure".

Passport is built around making social auth easier for developers, and lightening the load of writing login logic.
Most apps can get away without having the user need to create a new password.

Best practices are those which are shown in their extensive documentation, and the awesome tutorials that are around.